# update query with inner join access vba code

Tags: ms-access, vba, inner-join

I am trying to update a table from another one via a inner join query access vba. The field's name to be updated will be taken in a form.

I wrote this query, but it gives me error.

```
Dim dbs As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Set dbs = OpenDatabase("Dba_Savings.mdb")
dbs.Execute " UPDATE TblClient INNER JOIN TblImport ON TblClient.Account_Id = TblImport.Account_Id" _
& " SET TblClient." & Me.txtNewFieldName & " = TblImport." & Me.txtNewFieldName2 & ";"

dbs.Close
```

Can anyone help me please.

---

```
 Dim S As String
S = "UPDATE TblClient INNER JOIN TblImport ON TblClient.Account_Id = TblImport.Account_Id" _
    & " SET TblClient." & Me.txtNewFieldName & " = TblImport." & Me.txtNewFieldName2 & ";"
Debug.Print S
dbs.Execute S

UPDATE TblClient INNER JOIN TblImport ON TblClient.Account_Id = TblImport.Account_Id SET TblClient.S_B_Mar-14 = TblImport.S_B_Mar-14;
```

The SQL work perfectly and update the table, No error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Run time error '3075' Sytaxe error (missing operator) in query expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space between these two:

```
ON TblClient.Account_Id = TblImport.Account_Id" _ 
& "SET TblClient.
```

When building SQL in VBA, always assign the SQL to a string variable, then `Debug.Print` this variable. In this case, the error would be obvious.

Also this part is unnecessary, since it's already in the INNER JOIN:

```
WHERE TblClient.Account_Id = TblImport.Account_Id
```

**Edit**

Instead of

```vb
dbs.Execute " UPDATE TblClient INNER JOIN TblImport ON TblClient.Account_Id = TblImport.Account_Id" _ 
& " SET TblClient." & Me.txtNewFieldName & " = TblImport." & Me.txtNewFieldName2 & ";"
```

you do:

```vb
Dim S As String
S = "UPDATE TblClient INNER JOIN TblImport ON TblClient.Account_Id = TblImport.Account_Id" _ 
    & " SET TblClient." & Me.txtNewFieldName & " = TblImport." & Me.txtNewFieldName2 & ";"
Debug.Print S
dbs.Execute S
```

Ctrl+G opens the Immediate Window, this will show the output of `Debug.Print`. Please add this to your question.

Then, if it still gives an error, you can also create a new query, switch to SQL view, copy & paste the output, and try to run the query. You will probably get a better error message. Or at least highlight the problematic part.

Comment: Thanks, but i still have the same error, maybe the reference to the form is incorrect : " & Me.txtNewFieldName & "

Comment: Please **edit** your question, and add the output of the `Debug.Print`. @JamesLaguerre

Comment: @JamesLaguerre Please. `Debug.Print`. Use it. I promise it will help.

Comment: @JamesLaguerre: see Edit.

Comment: The VBA does not work, it gives error, but the SQL work fine after Debug.Print.

Comment: `DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE TblClient INNER JOIN TblImport ON TblClient.Account_Id = TblImport.Account_Id SET TblClient." & Me.txtNewFieldName & " = TblImport." & Me.txtNewFieldName2 & ";"`  This query work perfectly in module. I will use it. Many thanks Andre451 to help me solve the problem.